# How to have two separate authentication system in django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am in a requirement in which I need to have **two** different login/registration system.

```
1: One for the general user.
2: Second for the Channels admin.

Both will have different email id, password etc in two different tables. 
For the general     user it will go in the `auth_user` table and for the channel 
it I'd be creating another different models/table.
```

I know that django provides a complete authentication system that I can use for the **general user**. But how I can implement the same in case of channel admin at the same time?

I tried to look in django's documentation for the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and `AUTH_USER_MODEL`,

**I can not understand how the session will be set for the channel admin part.**

So if anyone can give me an idea how and what could be the ways to implement both of these at the same time.

Comment: is using the same system out of the question? I mean, you can implement your own login/auth logic but use Djangos "backend" if you will.

Comment: I am thinking of creating two different tables for both of these, for the general user it can be done by the default authentication system, but how to do this for the channel one? Can we use the default one for this also at the same time?

Comment: Do you need to have two diffrent types of sessions for the two diffrent types? It would seem to me that you would only want the session to store two diffrent types of information, right?

Comment: Yes I need to have two different sessions for both of these.

Comment: How come? What is the reasoning for this? If so, you need to make a special ChannelSession object and attach this to the django session.

Comment: Can it be done in the same django session if I don't want to have two different sessions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23934/discussion-between-limelights-and-am1ty9d9v)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/). You can have as many different ways to authenticate as you wish. Part of the information stored in the Session record is which authentication backend was used successfully. It's slightly involved, but they give you all of the control necessary to do pretty much whatever you like.

I used this on a system a number of years ago where the *primary* user/password information was coming from an external subscription management server. If the user/pass did not work on the normal User-auth system, I checked a different system. If it succeeded, I created a new User on the fly.

Answer (score -3):

Django has a complete built in admin login built in with interface also. check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: that was off-topic